# can't start jstatd with all access policy

Tags: java, jstatd

I'm trying to start jstatd on my server but I keep getting this error:

```
[ec2-user@ip-204-95-69 bin]$ sudo jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=/home/ec2-user/logstash-5.2.0/bin/jstatd.all.policy 
java.security.policy: error adding Entry:
    java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_92/lib/tools.jar
Could not create remote object
access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.rmi.server.ignoreSubClasses" "write")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.rmi.server.ignoreSubClasses" "write")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.System.setProperty(System.java:792)
    at sun.tools.jstatd.Jstatd.main(Jstatd.java:139)
[ec2-user@ip-204-95-69 bin]$
```

I've set my policy file to looks like this:

```
grant codebase "/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_92/lib/tools.jar" { permission java.security.AllPermission; };
```

what else do I need to set to get it to start? I tried it as `sudo` as well but that did not work either.

now if I run it with out the `-J` like this...`jstatd -p 9050 -Djava.security.policy=/homejstatd.all.policy -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=ip-address`

I keep getting this back...

```
[ec2-user@ip-204-95-69 bin]$ jstatd -p 9050 -Djava.security.policy=/home/ec2-user/logstash-5.2.0/bin/jstatd.all.policy -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=ip-address
usage: jstatd [-nr] [-p port] [-n rminame]
```